# Optimizing circle-circle collision response

Tags: c++, sfml

With SFML, I made an algorithm that calculates the trajectoris of two balls after a collision; it works fine, but  if I try with more than 30 balls, it freezes instantly or after 10-20 seconds.
I tried to avoid doing the same calculations multiple times, but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?(I have an high-end PC, the problem is not there)

Phi is the collision angle, dis is distance;

```
void collisionResponse(Circle &a, Circle &b)
{
    float mass1 = a.getMass();
    float mass2 = b.getMass();
    float disX = a.pos.x - b.pos.x;
    float disY = a.pos.y - b.pos.y;
    float phi = atan2(disY, disX);
    float speed1 = a.getSpeed();
    float speed2 = b.getSpeed();
    float angle1 = a.getAngle();
    float angle2 = b.getAngle();
    float v1x = speed1*cos((angle1 - phi));
    float v1y = speed1*sin((angle1 - phi));
    float v2x = speed2*cos((angle2 - phi));
    float v2y = speed2*sin((angle2 - phi));
    float f1x = ((mass1 - mass2)*v1x + (mass2 + mass2)*v2x) / (mass1+mass2);
    float f2x = ((mass1 + mass1)*v1x + (mass2 - mass1)*v2x) / (mass1+mass2);
    float f1y = v1y;
    float f2y = v2y;
    float cosphi = cos(phi);
    float sinphi = sin(phi);
    float cosphiPI = cos(phi + PI / 2);
    float sinphiPI = sin(phi + PI / 2);
    a.speed.x = cosphi*f1x + cosphiPI*f1y;
    a.speed.y = sinphi*f1x + sinphiPI*f1y;
    b.speed.x = cosphi*f2x + cosphiPI*f2y;
    b.speed.y = sinphi*f2x + sinphiPI*f2y;
    while (sqr(a.pos.x - b.pos.x) + sqr(a.pos.y -  b.pos.y) <= sqr(a.getRadius()+ b.getRadius()))
    {
        a.Move();
        b.Move();
    }
}
```

Comment: what formulas did you implemented ? I can't see why you even need angles

Comment: It's a bidimensional elastic collision, angles are required to calculate x and Y velocities

Comment: I made a mistake copying it, in the originale code it is right

Comment: Have you profiled your code ?

Comment: Freezes, meaning what? Does the while loop become an eternal loop?

Comment: No it doesn't because after a collision circles move at opposite directions

Comment: BTW, `cos(angle + PI/2) == - sin(angle)` and `sin(angle + PI/2) ==  cos(angle)`.